# Webelement List and choose only one

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please assist me in following case:
I have Webelement list with following elements:

```
Double Chance (Ordinary Time)
1X2 (Ordinary Time)
12 (Full Event)
Odd/Even (Full Event)
Over / Under (Full Time)
Odd/Even (Ordinary Time)
Halftime / Fulltime (Ordinary Time)
Over Under (Ordinary Time)
1X2 (1st Half)
Odd/Even (1st Half)
```

I have to confirm that exists among them i.e 1X2 (Ordinary Time) and if exists, then just to work with it. If does not exist, finish the test. below is my code with which I tried but without success:

```
List<WebElement> allAvailsbleMarkets =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main[@class='be-root__main']/be-match2/be-single-view-layout/div[3]
 for (int p = 0; p < allAvailsbleMarkets.size(); p++) {
 System.out.println(allAvailsbleMarkets.get(p).getText());
 }
  if (allAvailsbleMarkets.contains("1X2 (Ordinary Time)")) {
                "GO to that element"
 } else {
 System.out.println("chosen Bet Type is not in the list of offered ones");
 }
```

Unfortunatelly, I am getting always that element is not found. What am I doing incorrect?

@f1sh It isw checking all options, bu I need only one:

```
Tip can not be posted
Tip can not be posted since that chosen Bet Type is not in the list of offered ones
Tip can not be posted since that chosen Bet Type is not in the list of offered ones
Tip can not be posted since that chosen Bet Type is not in the list of offered ones
Tip can not be posted since that chosen Bet Type is not in the list of offered ones
And until it finish counting
```

Comment: You check it a ``List`` of ``WebElement``s contains a ``String``. That will always be false, because it contains items of type ``WebElement``. Check each WebElement if it's getText() method returns a value that ``equals`` your desired ``String``.

Comment: @f1sh Then, how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check it a `List` of `WebElement`s contains a `String`. That will always be false, because it contains items of type `WebElement`.

Check each WebElement if it's `getText()` method returns a value that `equals` your desired `String`:

```
for(WebElement e:allAvailsbleMarkets){
  if("1X2 (Ordinary Time)".equals(e.getText())){
     //go to that element

     //an element has been found, so stop the checking loop:
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @f1sh for solving my problem

Comment: actually have another issue, now. Just look what I added in question body and again thank you Please just assist in this issue

Comment: @Zoran add a ``break`` to exit the loop when the desired element was found, i updated the answer