# Could not match one element from Webelement List with Array list element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is additional issue, which I came-up on (question link is: [Webelement List and choose only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027642/webelement-list-and-choose-only-one)) 
Could someone assist in case on which I stuck:
I have following list of WebElements:

```
Double Chance (Ordinary Time)
1X2 (Ordinary Time)
12 (Full Event)
Odd/Even (Full Event)
Over / Under (Full Time)
Odd/Even (Ordinary Time)
Halftime / Fulltime (Ordinary Time)
Over Under (Ordinary Time)
Double Chance (1st Half)
1X2 (1st Half)
```

Found exact element (and only one I need from above list, i.e 1X2 (Ordinary Time)) with help of @f1sh

```
List<WebElement> allAvailsbleMarkets = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//main[@class='be-root__main']/be-match2/be-single-view-layout/div[3]\n"
                        + "//be-markets-page2/div/div/ul/li//be-outcomes2//h4"));

for(WebElement e:allAvailsbleMarkets){
if("1X2 (Ordinary Time)".equals(e.getText())){
 //go to that element

 //an element has been found, so stop the checking loop:
 break;
  }
}
```

But, now I forgot that I have several languages and created array list as follows:

```
 public static List<String> ordinaryTimeTranslations = Arrays.asList(
        "1X2 (Ordinary Time)",
        "1X2 (Regularno vreme)",
        "1X2 (Ordinær Spilletid)",
        "1X2 (Reguläre Zeit)"
}
```

So, my issue is how to (and got stuck there) pickup form Array list exact match (in above case it is English version). Tried with above code but it does not match my List Webelement with needed in Array list
Result is that never finds needed member of Array.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another loop inside the first one:

```
for (WebElement e : allAvailsbleMarkets)
    for (String txt : ordinaryTimeTranslations) {
        if(txt.equals(e.getText())) {
            // Match found
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Understood, that is what I been missing. Thank you'